# Removing entries from LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm experimenting with Linux shared libraries and added an entry (`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`) to **$LD_LIBRARY_PATH**. Now I wish it gone. How can I do that?

PS. Typing `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before I added an entry gave me an empty line. Now it says:

> path/to/library:

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If previously it gave you empty line it (most probably) means that the variable was not set (by default it is not set), so you can just unset it:

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

A few other options to experiment:

```
export MY_PATH=/my/path
export MY_PATH2=/my/path2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${MY_PATH}:${MY_PATH2}"
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/my/path:/my/path2
```

Removing path from the end:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH/:${MY_PATH2}/}"
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/my/path
```

Similarily, removing path from the beginning (if set as above):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH/${MY_PATH}:/}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using `bash`, you can set it back to an empty path using:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=""
```

And if you want to un-export it:

```
export -n LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) is a great piece of documentation to help out with this kind of problem.